# PhantomJS only output part of the HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, phantomjs

I am trying to get html with javascript outputs and it looks like this:

phantomjs.php:

```
$phantom_script = dirname(__FILE__). '\phantomjs.js';

$response =  exec ('phantomjs ' . $phantom_script);

echo htmlspecialchars($response);
```

phantomjs.js:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://www.vedur.is/vedur/spar/stadaspar#station=422', function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

The result is:

```
<img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="http://potency-cnt.teljari.is/potency/potency.php?o=35;p=%2Fvedur%2Fspar%2Fstadaspar;i=1;cv=2;w=1366;h=768;c=32;j=1.5;u=1431693083;z=0;l=en-US;v=0;e=0;sl=0;uid=bfd17714c46187a29d8d512ca6f2040a;chsum=05cd66be9ba63b0fc9104a7e7117e602"></body></html>
```

But I would like to get the whole html.

Comment: Did you try curl to fetch data, maybe on server side smth is redirecting you to that image tag?

Comment: I thing there is a problem with the exec function